# AWS Lambda (NET 6) & Cognito: How to use Swagger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, amazon-cognito

I am developing AWS Lambda (NET 6)=>RDS and use Cognito as Identity provider. I do not develop a client app because it will be done later.

How to use Swagger to test Lambda using authentication? i.e. to use Cognito groups etc to test restriction on methods performing via Swagger?